# Efficient way to generate report data

Tags: javascript, business-intelligence

I have a some report data available with me which i am fetching from say a webService.
The data is in JSON format of the form :

- Year -> Region ->Items == has the data for 12 months(a simple Array)
- (3)  ->   (3)  -> (10)
- i.e. 3 Year, each contains 5 regions, and each region has say 10 products.

what is the efficient way to generate various representations of this data in javascript.
or What methodologies are to be adopted for report generation of such a kind.

I am Building a BI solution using javascript.
My Application uses the data in different formats for the respective components.
Switching between these components constantly involves regeneration of data.
Hence, either i need the datasets for these components to be generated in advance or have an efficient way to do it on the go.

Answer (score 0):

> i need the datasets for these components to be generated in
>   advance

I believe this is a simple straightforward approach; aggreggate and store your data in separate tables before hand.

This would require a cron or some sort of middle process.  Instead of processing and generating reports in javascript on each page load data would be retrieved aggregated and stored in a seperate table.

javascript would then only need to retrieve and present the data in the aggregated table.

Comment: Yes! that would eliminate most of the performance overhead and writing the processing and generating logic in javascript. What are methods/tools available for data generation,aggregation, so that it would reduce a lot of code writing and logic building effort.

Comment: @HimanshuSoni What storage system/language are you using in your webService? It might be easiest to keep everything there

Comment: I can work on it, to aggregate the data on the server side.
But, its unachievable over there. And i am forced to do it on the client side. How can i generate the data, beforeHand. And right now, i dont have a webservice for it. It a tentative source of data.
I am also looking for an Excel parser, as a workaround solution